# Association Type Mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting this error:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Design(#2199041060) expected, got String(#2151988680))

I am trying to create an Event whereby the user enters some information for the event and at the same time selects a Design. Each time I click on the Create button the error happens.

Here are my models:

```
class Design < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to  :event        # User creates an Event and selects only one Design
  belongs_to  :user         # User could also create a Design 
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :user     # A user can create as many events
  has_one     :design   # User can only select one design for this event
end
```

Here is my Event Controller

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])
  @user = current_user
  @designs = Design.all

  if @event.save
    flash[:success] = "Event created"
    @user.events << @event 
    redirect_to events_path
  end
end
```

Here is my Event View:

```
<%= form_for @event, :url => {:action => 'create', :id => @event.id } do |e| %>
<p>Enter a title for this event: <%= e.text_field :title %> </p>

<p>Select a design:</p> 
 <ul class = "list">
    <% @designs.each do |design| %>
        <li><%= e.radio_button :design, design.id %> <%= design.name %></li>
    <% end %>
 </ul>
    <%= e.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Without the full error I am only making a stab here but it looks like at some point the Database was expecting you to pass a Design object and instead got a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= e.radio_button :design, design.id %>
```

You're not actually passing a whole design object to your event model - just the id, so this should actually reflect that by instead using:

```
<%= e.radio_button :design_id, design.id %>
```

Edit:
and add to your event model:

```
def design_id=(the_id)
  return unless the_id
  the_design = Design.find_by_id(the_id)
  self.design = the_design if the_design
end
```

Comment: Nope this did not work, I got this error undefined method `design_id' for #<Event:0x00000106057150>` I am suppose to pass in the Event id to the Design model, right? Since an Event can have only one Design.

Comment: Ah, because it's has-one. Ok, you'll need to add the method I'll add i the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

In your view, change :design to :design_id.